# n-th power of a matrix using the division of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-calculus

Consider the matrix 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 1 & -1\\
2 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

1. Calculate $A^3-3A^2+2A$.
2. What is the remainder of the division of the polynomial $X^n$ by the polynomial $X^3-3X^2+2X$.
3. Calculate $A^n$ for every natural number $n$.

I was solving the following problem and I was stuck in it. For part 1) the answer was the zero matrix. In part 2) I use the usual division and i get the following
$$
X^n=X^{n-3}(X^3-3X^2+2X)+3X^{n-1}-2X^{n-2}.
$$ 
When I pass to part 3) and using part 1) and 2), we obtain
$$
A^n=3A^{n-1}-2A^{n-2}.
$$ 
Using the fact that $A^3-3A^2+2A=O_{3\times 3}$. but if I use this answer for calculating $A^2$ the answer is not correct, so I think $A^n$ obtained is not correct. Now, one can use the diagonalization of the matrix $A$ and obtain
$$
A^n=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2^n & 1 & 1-2^n\\
2^n & 0 & 2^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Can you help me in proving part 2 (if not correct) and part 3 without using the diagonalization method.

Comment: Your part 2) is incomplete. e.g. for $n=6$ one has $X^6 = ((X^3+3X^2+7X+15I)(X^3-3X^2+2X)+(31X^2-30X))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$x^n = q(x)(x^3-3x^2+2x) + r(x) = q(x)x(x-1)(x-2)+r(x)$$
for polynomials $q,r \in \Bbb{R}[x]$ where $\deg r \le 2$. Plugging in $x = 0,1,2$ gives
$$r(0) = 0, \quad r(1)=1, \quad r(2)=2^n$$
so $r(x) = (2^{n-1}-1)x^2+(-2^{n-1}+2)x$. Now we get
$$A^n = q(A)(A^3-3A^2+2A) + r(A) = r(A) = (2^{n-1}-1)A^2+(-2^{n-1}+2)A$$
which yields precisely your result.

Comment: Many thanks. @mechanodroid

Answer (score 0):

You could use induction.

For $n=1$, your statement is true.

Assuming
$$
A^n=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2^n & 1 & 1-2^n\\
2^n & 0 & 2^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then 
$$
A^{n+1} = AA^n = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 1 & -1\\
2 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2^n & 1 & 1-2^n\\
2^n & 0 & 2^n
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2^n - 2^n & 1 & 1-2^n - 2^n\\
2\cdot2^n & 0 & 2\cdot2^n
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2^{n+1} & 1 & 1-2^{n+1}\\
2^{n+1} & 0 & 2^{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So
$$ 
A^n = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
-2^n & 1 & 1-2^n\\
2^n & 0 & 2^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is true for every natural number $n$

Comment: Yes it is correct if I use diagonalization, but here they want to find $A^n$ using part 1 and part 2. so I need help in proving these two parts. @jazhang

Comment: I edit my question to know what I want.